# push new changes to a new branch without interrupting the current branch

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a feature for a week, I have many uncommitted changes, suddenly I need to push something for my colleague, how do I put on hold my current feature and do that? I don't want to commit my half way work then switch to develop branch, and then create a new branch from there, this will ruin the commit history.

Answer (score 1):

Committing the work locally is better than stashing it in my opinion. When you want to continue the disrupted work you simply checkout the commit you made, do more modifications followed by a `git commit --amend` to add on to the tip commit of your branch. This will ensure you get the commit history you are looking for.

Comment: `git stash` just makes a commit (actually 2 or 3) under the hood.  There is nothing wrong using stash.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing a `git stash` would be the most expedient thing here.  Just type:

```
git stash
```

This will stash your current working directory (and stage), and leave you with a clean slate.  After this, you may switch branches and push whatever is required.  When you return to your feature branch, type:

```
git stash apply
```

to return to the state in which you left.  Incidentally, it is worth noting that stash itself actually makes 2 (or sometimes 3) commits under the hood.  You could even make your own commit, and then amend it later, but give stash a try first.

Comment: What if I alrdy make changes 1 one branch? I cna manually copy out few file and do git stash.

Comment: @XieXieFang I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is:

`git stash`

Which stashes the current changes to your branch, so that they can be reapplied later, taking you back to the last commit.

Then you can change branches, push etc.

To get your old code back just change back to the branch where you stashed and use:

`git stash pop`

which applies the most recent stash and then deletes the stash once it is applied.

Comment: git stash apply vs git stash pop what is the different?

Comment: `git stash pop` applies the stash and removes it from the stack.  `git stash apply` leaves it in the stash in case you need to ever use it again.